# What is the best way to locate a specific tag?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, data-structures

Let us say that I am visiting a webpage that I have no control over and it is constantly stable. 
What is the best way to specify a tag position and how can I write in Javascript?

Currently I thought about saving absolute position from the top of the DOM tree to the tag, but I have no idea how to write it in Javascript to save the structure and find it again from the structure. And is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Get the webpage with PHP:

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.domain.com/page.html');
?>
```

Get the contents of the wanted tag with JQuery:

```
$('#tag').html();
```

Comment: This is a particularly unhelpful answer, considering that the OP specifically asked about how to do it in Javascript.

Comment: I've posted the better way, like asked for.

Comment: I want to know more about something that does not rely on "id" since it might not have an id. I know it is a strange request, but I couldn't find anyone mentioned before on the web.

Comment: You mean it has always the same position on the page, and you want to get that position?

Comment: Well, yes. I mean the tag position. Not relative to the layout but the position inside html dom tree.

Comment: I don't know how to do that in Javascript, in PHP is fairly simple.